# Jenkins - Git - Failing to checkout from Git Repository

Tags: git, github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a git repo that I am using for a build in Jenkins. The build fails consistently with the following error:

```
Seen 1 remote branch
Commencing build of Revision 30c6a7a5e6fd30e8519fb3d604a1c195d48ea4fc (origin/master)
Checking out Revision 30c6a7a5e6fd30e8519fb3d604a1c195d48ea4fc (origin/master)
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe config core.sparsecheckout
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe checkout -f 30c6a7a5e6fd30e8519fb3d604a1c195d48ea4fc
FATAL: Could not checkout null with start point 30c6a7a5e6fd30e8519fb3d604a1c195d48ea4fc
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not checkout null with start point 30c6a7a5e6fd30e8519fb3d604a1c195d48ea4fc
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$8.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1497)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.AbstractGitAPIImpl.checkout(AbstractGitAPIImpl.java:64)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.checkout(CliGitAPIImpl.java:87)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.checkout(GitAPI.java:208)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1273)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.access$1100(GitSCM.java:57)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$4.invoke(GitSCM.java:1232)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$4.invoke(GitSCM.java:1208)
    at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:2439)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:328)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine$1$1.run(Engine.java:63)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe checkout -f 30c6a7a5e6fd30e8519fb3d604a1c195d48ea4fc" returned status code 1:
stdout: 
stderr: error: unable to create file
```

There is one branch master and the sha-1 is the latest checkout. Also the following appears :

```
Note: checking out '30c6a7a5e6fd30e8519fb3d604a1c195d48ea4fc'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b new_branch_name

HEAD is now at 30c6a7a... Update README.md
```

I am not sure why jenkins thinks the repo is in headless state?

Comment: is your repo empty?
Also, please see:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18363658/trouble-with-jenkins-and-git

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, and what was wrong was that the file path was too long, so I changed my workspace to be a shorter string and it worked again.